# Как спарсить весь html через Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Мне нужно получить текст html кода сайта.

```
import scrapy
response = scrapy.Request(url)
html = response????
```

В общем я не смог разобраться с этим сам, помогите)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, scrapy так не работает, он для массового парсинга, там надо описывать конфиги, коллбэки и прочее. И запускать специальным образом https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: @CrazyElf ок, спасибо

Comment: Если хотите просто скачать страничку используйте библиотеку `requests`, там страница будет в `response.content` (с хтмл тэгами) либо в `response.text` (просто текст)

Comment: @CrazyElf от неё защита на сайтах. Типо там не парсится html, а получается фигня какая-то. Я так понимаю связано с подгрузкой ja

Comment: Сайты, у которых контент подгружается через `JS` это не защита, это так сайты написаны просто. Там надо использовать `Selenium` тогда. А если защита именно, то просто надо нормальные `header`-ы передавать, чтобы сайт думал, что обращается браузер.

Comment: @CrazyElf ок, спасибо, попробую юзер агенты и другие параметры написать